# Run Time Error 429 - Active X cannot sent email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have created the below macro but when I try to send the error I get the Error on:

```
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

This was successfully working for a few weeks before I got the below error. This is occuring on several email sending macros that I have created.

```
Sub SSTrades()

    Rows("1:14").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("R:R").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SS ID"
    Range("R2").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    File Location And Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("File Location " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") & ".xlsx")


    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim strbody As String


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to send FX Report ", vbYesNo, "Continue?")

    If CarryOn = vbYes Then

    email body desciption
    strbody = "<font size=""3"">" & _
              "Hi All,<br><br>" & _
              "Please find attached the daily FX report" & "<br>"


    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .to = "Teams"
        .CC = "TEAM"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = " FX Trades " & Date
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "team"
        .send
    End With

    MsgBox ("Complete")

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

> Run TIme Error '429' Active X component cant create object

Comment: If you get the error on this line `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` it means Outlook is not installed (or at least not found). Try re-installing Outlook. Note that something like `outlook.com` will not work.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  Is it `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` or `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)`?

Comment: The error occurs on Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") . When i run it the code line by line it gets to this line and then spits out the error.

Comment: So please try to figure out what changed since *"This was successfully working for a few weeks"*. Did you upgrade/change your Office version? If not try a re-install. If yes tell what version you used before and which verision you are using now.

Comment: Microsoft Support: [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications-b6070e15-ea78-4349-2751-72bdb5f186f7)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you run both applications in the same security context (run as administrators or without admin privileges).

The [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications) article describes possible reasons for the error described.

It is not clear which Office version you deal with, so the following information may be helpful:

The Click2Run edition of Office 2010 doesn't support automation. See [Office 2010 Click-to-Run compatibility with add-ins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982431/office-2010-click-to-run-compatibility-with-add-ins) for more information. Also, you may find the [How to: Verify Whether Outlook Is a Click-to-Run Application on a Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/verify-if-outlook-is-a-click-to-run-application-on-a-computer) article.